# How to fetch all user's data from aws-cloud-directory?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-directory-services

I am new in AWS-Cloud-Directory . I have created a directory to store all the user's basic information . I can create a new user node and search for a specific user . I can fetch all the information of a single user using the aws-sdk for nodejs. Now I want to fetch all the user's data from my directory in a single API call . I can do that calling the same API ( to fetch single user data ) `n`  times for `n` users . But it's very costly . Have anyone any idea ? Does AWS actually support it ?

Comment: You can use this as a reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/clouddirectory/latest/APIReference/API_BatchRead.html

Comment: Thank you @SunnyParekh for your suggestion . I checked it and found that there is a read limit ( 200 objects ) in BatchRead . And it's also count all objects in the path . As , I don't know how many users will be there I don't find it suitable for me . But it would be a fine solution if there is no limit .

Comment: You can have a recursive function for it wherein you can iterate the loop for each 200 objects batch and get a final array of all the objects. It is similar to batch read operation from DynamoDB. The limit over there is 25 objects. So we need to iterate the same operation after every 25 objects and prepare the final array.

Comment: Thank you very much @SunnyParekh . I have implemented your idea and it's pretty good . Firstly I fetch all the user's ids . Then in each batch call I use 20 object ids to get 20 users details at a time . I make these batch call asynchronous , so it's pretty fast now ! Thank you very much once again .

Comment: You are welcome! I am happy that I was able to help you.